# Referências com mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose, referência

Atualmente possuo 3 collections no meu projeto, e preciso que 2 delas("Course" e "Lesson"), tenham uma ligação, eu quero que ao adicionar uma "lesson" ela seja inserida em um "course" através de um push, porém tá dando esse erro:

> (node:16156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

meu código ta asssim, alguém consegue me ajudar? Estou iniciando agora com nodejs

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
require('./config/database');
const cors = require('cors')

const usersRouter = require('./app/routes/users');
const courseRouter = require('./app/routes/courses');
const lessonRouter = require('./app/routes/lessons');

const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());


app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/courses', courseRouter);
app.use('/courses', lessonRouter.courseDependent);

module.exports = app;
```

**models/course**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, text: true},
    body: {type: String, text: true},
    lessons: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Lesson'
    }],
    authorU: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);
```

**models/lesson**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let lessonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, text: true},
    body: {type: String, text: true},
    lessons: {type: String, required: true, text: true},
    courseRef: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Course',
        required: true
    },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Lesson', lessonSchema);
```

**routes/lessons.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const courseDependentRoute = express.Router();
const WithAuth = require('../middlewares/auth');
 
const Lesson = require('../models/lesson');
const Course = require('../models/course');

courseDependentRoute.get('/:id/lessons/new', async(req, res) => {
    try {
         let lesson = Lesson();
         res.status(200).json({courseRef: req.params.id, lesson: lesson})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'Problemas para criar nova aula'})
    }
})

courseDependentRoute.post('/:id/newLesson', WithAuth, async(req, res) => {
    const { title, body, lessons } = req.body;
    let lesson = new Lesson({ title: title, body: body, lessons: lessons, courseRef: req.params.id })

    // try {
        await lesson.save();
        let course = await Course.findById(req.params.id);
        course.lesson.push(lesson);
        await course.save();
        res.status(200).json(course);
    // } catch (error) {
    //     res.status(500).json({error: 'Problemas para criar novo curso'})
    // }
});

module.exports = { courseDependent: courseDependentRoute };
```

Comment: Veja que `course.lesson` deve ser um array para poder fazer o `push`. O erro diz que ele é undefined, então cheque se `course` possui esse atributo `lesson`

Comment: Realmente, era isso muito obrigado, falta de atenção a minha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução

- Altere, no arquivo `models/course`, o atributo do Schema de `lessons` para `lesson` ou
- Mude a linha de erro para `course.lessons.push(lesson)`

Com uma leitura atenta ao erro, consegue-se perceber que ele indica que `course.lesson` é `undefined` e, por isso, não se pode realizar um `push` (método exclusivo para Arrays).

Nesse sentido, o que ocasiona esse retorno `undefined` é o fato de a definição impor o atributo no plural **`lessons`** em vez de `lesson` sem o "s".